A very basic Game theory doubt
I was going through the Blockchain Documentation and on section 1.8 they talk about Nash Equilibria
My very modest understanding of the term is that it is a set of strategies for each player where they have no incentive to switch independently to the other alternative.
Now the first one here is described as having two Nash equilibria

But this is described as having only one. And I cannot understand why that is the case, since isn't this situation similar to the above?


For the second game, The Rabbit/Rabbit state (R/R going forward) is not at equilibrium.  $A$ can switch to S and improve their payout, while also hurting $B$.  Similarly, $B$ can profitably switch to $S$, so the two drift into S/S.

In the first diagram, at (rabbit,rabbit) no one can improve their score by choosing snag instead and also in the (snag,snag) situation you cant improve by choosing rabbit.
Thus there a two equilibrium: either (snag,snag) or (rabbit,rabbit).
In the second diagram:
at the (rabbit, rabbit) point, either one can improve their score from 2 to at least 3 by choosing snag. Thus the only nash equilibrium is (snag,snag).
It is easy to miss if you see that the difference in payout has been switched in the (rabbit,snag) situation.

If in the second diagram we can improve the score from 2 to at least 3 ,then isn't it similarly possible to go from 1 to 2 in the first case? I'm sorry if I'm being real dumb but I just don't get it.

You're not being dumb at all just mixing it up. If we are in the first diagram in (rabbit,rabbit) if you get 1 point, but if you try to say snag instead and the other still says rabbit you get 0 points. Try to look at the points in the diagram carefully. The one with the most points in (snag, rabbit) situation is switched in the two diagrams.

Let's layout the game mathematically,

Players- {Alice,Bob}
Action Sets, $A_1$={Stag, Rabbit} $\hspace{2mm}$ $A_2$={Stag, Rabbit}
Payoff functions,
$$\pi_1:A_1 \times A_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$\pi_2:A_1 \times A_2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

The preference functions are defined as per the above table,

Plan: We can figure out the Best Response Set of player 1 and 2 and then look the intersection of the Graphs of Best responses to figure out the Nash Equilibria,
$$BR_1(c_2)= \{c_1\in A_1 | \pi_1(c_1,c_2) \ge \pi_1(c_1^1,c_2) 
\hspace{2mm}, \forall c_1^1 \in A_1\}$$ and similarly $BR_2(c_1)$
For the first game
$BR_1($Stag$)$={Stag};$BR_2($Stag$)$={Stag}
$BR_1($Rabbit$)$={Rabbit};$BR_2($Rabbit$)$={Rabbit}
Now we can plot the $GR(BR_1)=\{(c_1,c_2)\in A_1 \times A_2 |c_1 \in BR_1(c_2)\}$
and $GR(BR_2)=\{(c_1,c_2)\in A_1 \times A_2 |c_2 \in BR_2(c_1)\}$ and look at their intersection to figure out the equilibrium,
$GR(BR_1$)={(Stag,Stag),(Rabbit, Rabbit)}and similarly the $GR(BR_2$)={(Stag,Stag),(Rabbit, Rabbit)}
Now observe for the above two sets, the intersection,
i.e., the Nash-Equilibria turn out to be (Stag,Stag) and (Rabbit, Rabbit)
You can use the use the same method to find out the Nash-equilibrium for the second game yourself(Its pretty Straightforward).
